# update column value when other columns change

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns (value1, value2 and total).

When you update the value1 or value2 column, I need the sum of the two to be updated in the total column.

I know there's a way to trigger it, but since it does it after the update and updates a column, won't it stay in a loop?

Comment: No, it won't...

Comment: Why you use static column? use generated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  value1 INT,
  value2 INT,
  total INT AS (value1 + value2) 
);
INSERT INTO test (value1, value2) VALUES (1,2), (3,4);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT,5,6,DEFAULT), (DEFAULT,7,8,DEFAULT);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | value1 | value2 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 |
| 3 | 5 | 6 | 11 |
| 4 | 7 | 8 | 15 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vPdoXekV)

Remember - you cannot set (in INSERT) or update (in UPDATE, INSERT ODKU, MERGE, etc.) the value in generated column, you can only retrieve its value.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to check if the update affects to value1 or value2 to trigger it:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_total_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.value1 != OLD.value1 OR NEW.value2 != OLD.value2 THEN
        SET NEW.total = NEW.value1 + NEW.value2;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: IF is obviously excess. The row must be saved anycase (fake updates are rare).